# Median of three, pivot

Tags: python, quicksort

I'm looking for the **median of three**, using this for a pivot in a QuickSort. I would not like to import any statistics library because I believe it creates a bit of overhead which I would like to reduce as much as possible.

```
def median(num_list):

if (num_list[0] > num_list[len(num_list) - 1]) and (num_list[0] < num_list[int(len(num_list)//2)]):
    return num_list[0]
elif (num_list[int(len(num_list)//2)] > num_list[len(num_list) - 1]) and (num_list[0] > num_list[int(len(num_list)//2)]):
    return num_list[int(len(num_list)//2)]
else:
    return num_list[len(num_list) - 1]
```

this seems to be returning the last else statement every time, I'm stumped...

Comment: I think you're not covering all of the possible orderings of the values. The first item can be the median if middle > first > last (and I think your code gets it right then), but also if last > first > middle (don't think it works then). You can write out all six possible arrangements of the values 1,2,3, write out code that gets them all right (even if it's verbose), and then simplify from there (e.g., if there's an `if cond1 and cond2` and an `if cond2 and cond3`, you can rearrange into an `if cond2` with two ifs under it).

Comment: (And you don't necessarily have to do the simplification part, though your teacher and your inner perfectionist might like it! You gotta be able to get code right to ship useful things; the rest is optional, or you can build it up with time.)

Comment: Thanks Twotwotwo, that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Quicksort you do not usually want just to know the median of three, you want to arrange the three values so the smallest is in one spot, the median in another, and the maximum in yet another. But if you really just want the median of three, here are two ways, plus another that rearranges.

Here's a short way to find the median of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```
return a + b + c - min(a, b, c) - max(a, b, c)
```

If you want only comparisons, and to get what may be the quickest code, realize that three comparisons may need to be executed but you want to try for only two. (Two comparisons can handle four cases, but there are six arrangements of three objects.) Try

```
if a < b:
    if b < c:
        return b
    elif a < c:
        return c
    else:
        return a
else:
    if a < c:
        return a
    elif b < c:
        return c
    else:
        return b
```

If you want to rearrange the values so `a <= b <= c`,

```
if a > b:
    a, b = b, a
if b > c:
    b, c = c, b
if a > b
    a, b = b, a
return b
```

Comment: I like the math solution, it's neat.

Answer (score 1):

Let Python do the work for you. Sort the three elements, then return the middle one.

```
def median(num_list):
    return sorted([num_list[0], num_list[len(num_list) // 2], num_list[-1]])[1]
```

Comment: Mhmm, looks good, but I will try to run all called functions on my own. Thankyou Kindall.

Comment: @FloSuess, what do you mean by ```run all called functions on my own```?

Comment: Well sorry, that was a bit weird, I mean in this particular assignment I was designing a QuickSort algorithm. Using the sorted function would be cheating in a way.

Answer (score 1):

Using `min` and `max`:

```
>>> numlist = [21, 12, 16]
>>> a, b, c = numlist
>>> max(min(a,b), min(b,c), min(a,c))
16
>>>
```

---

Going out on a limb - I have a functional streak so here is the itertools equivalent, even though it means importing a module

```
>>> import itertools
>>> numlist = [21, 12, 16]
>>> z = itertools.combinations(numlist, 2)
>>> y = itertools.imap(min, z)
>>> max(y)
16
```

Comment: I like this, since it is in some ways shorter than my expression using `max` and `min`. It does end up using five comparisons, however, compared to my four.